# CsvHelper CsvWriter is empty when source DataTable contains less than 12 rows

Tags: c#, stream, csvhelper

When writing to stream (Maybe other destinations too) CsvHelper does not return anything if my DataTable contains less than 12 rows. I tested adding rows one by one until I get a result in the string myCsvAsString variable.

Anyone ran into this problem? Here is the code I am using to reproduce it:

```
        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            if (includeHeaders)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    csvWriter.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
                }

                csvWriter.NextRecord();
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    csvWriter.WriteField(row[i]);
                }

                csvWriter.NextRecord();
            }

            csvWriter.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string myCsvAsString = reader.ReadToEnd();
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the issue, I was flushing the csvWriter but I did not flush the StreamWriter.

I added writer.Flush() just after csvWriter.Flush() and the stream is complete.